# How to access "main" Navigator (of MaterialApp) after it's created?

Tags: flutter

I have following code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  _mustBeCalledWhenNavigatorIsReady() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
      .authStateChanges()
      .listen((User user) {
        if (user == null) {
          // the problem is that this happens before navigator is created and _navigatorKey.currentState == null
          // I need to call _mustBeCalledWhenNavigatorIsReady when the navigator instance is already created
          _navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed('auth/login');
        } else {
          _navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed('/');
        }
      });
  }

  MyApp() {
    _mustBeCalledWhenNavigatorIsReady();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      // navigatorObservers: [],
      navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: router.getRouteGenerator(), // uses router from package fluro internally - so its just a route generator
      initialRoute: 'auth/login',
    );
  }
}
```

What I need as described in code comments is to init some listeners after router is created and do it only once. However I have access to router only in route widgets. Is there any easy way of getting know when "main" navigator of MaterialApp is created?

Comment: check `MaterialApp.builder`

Comment: Already checked - navigator is not yet created in "builder" func

Comment: weird: in builder "child" argument passed to it is actually "Navigator-[LabeledGlobalKey<NavigatorState>#252cd" but still _navigatorKey.currentState is null...

Comment: because the `Navigator` is created but not attached to the widgets tree - this gives you a chance to assign your custom `Navigator` for example - you need to wait for a next frame for `State` to be valid - simple `Future(() {stuff to execute})` will do that

Comment: or you can use `SchedulerBinding.scheduleFrameCallback` or any other similar method from `SchedulerBinding` mixin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MaterialApp(
 //....
 initialRoute: initialRoutes(),
 //....
)

string initialRoutes() {

 final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  FirebaseAuth.instance
   .authStateChanges()
   .listen((User user) {
   if (user == null) {
     // the problem is that this happens before navigator is created and 
     // _navigatorKey.currentState == null
     // I need to call _mustBeCalledWhenNavigatorIsReady when the navigator 
     // instance 
     // is already created
     return 'auth/login';
   } else {
     return '/';
   }
  });
 }
}
```